# Create a complete Linux virtual machine infrastructure in Azure with Terraform

Tags: azure, ssh, virtual-machine, terraform, public-key

So I'm very new creating virtual machines and Microsoft Azure. I'm trying to create one in terraform and link to my Azure account. I have been following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/terraform-create-complete-vm. For some background; my goal is to create the VM, log in via ssh on a vpn and log the logins

Using the sample code they provide however, I get this error:

```
azurerm_virtual_machine.myterraformvm: compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidParameter" Message="The value of parameter linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.keyData is invalid." Target="linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.keyData"
```

This is my code: `terraform_azure.tf`

```
# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  tenant_id       = "myid"
  client_id       = "myclientid"
  client_secret   = "mysecret"
  subscription_id = "mysubscr"
}

# Create a resource group if it doesn’t exist
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myterraformgroup" {
  name     = "myResourceGroup"
  location = "eastus"

  tags {
    environment = "Terraform Demo"
  }
}

# Create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "myterraformnetwork" {
  name                = "myVnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"

  tags {
    environment = "Terraform Demo"
  }
}

# Create subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "myterraformsubnet" {
  name                 = "mySubnet"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.myterraformnetwork.name}"
  address_prefix       = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

# Create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "myterraformpublicip" {
  name                = "myPublicIP"
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"

  tags {
    environment = "Terraform Demo"
  }
}

# Create Network Security Group and rule
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "myterraformnsg" {
  name                = "myNetworkSecurityGroup"
  location            = "eastus"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"

  security_rule {
    name                       = "SSH"
    priority                   = 1001
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }

  tags {
    environment = "Terraform Demo"
  }
}

# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "myterraformnic" {
  name                      = "myNIC"
  location                  = "eastus"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
  network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.myterraformnsg.id}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "myNicConfiguration"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.myterraformsubnet.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.myterraformpublicip.id}"
  }

  tags {
    environment = "Terraform Demo"
  }
}

# Generate random text for a unique storage account name
resource "random_id" "randomId" {
  keepers = {
    # Generate a new ID only when a new resource group is defined
    resource_group = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
  }

  byte_length = 8
}

# Create storage account for boot diagnostics
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "mystorageaccount" {
  name                     = "diag${random_id.randomId.hex}"
  resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
  location                 = "eastus"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  tags {
    environment = "Terraform Demo"
  }
}

# Create virtual machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "myterraformvm" {
  name                  = "myVM"
  location              = "eastus"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.myterraformnic.id}"]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myOsDisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04.0-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "myvm"
    admin_username = "azureuser"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true

    ssh_keys {
      path     = "/home/azureuser/.ssh/authorized_keys"
      key_data = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz{snip}hwhqT9h"
    }
  }

  boot_diagnostics {
    enabled     = "true"
    storage_uri = "${azurerm_storage_account.mystorageaccount.primary_blob_endpoint}"
  }

  tags {
    environment = "Terraform Demo"
  }
}
```

I'm wondering why this is. In the error `The value of parameter linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.keyData is invalid` says something about my public key? Where am I/should I be setting this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass in the key content, not path to the key:

> NOTE: Rather than defining this in-line you can source this from a
>   local file using the file interpolation function - for example
>   key_data = "${file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")}".

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html#key_data

Comment: If I link to my pub in ssh folder I get "Destination path for SSH public keys is currently limited to its default value /home/azureuser/.ssh/authorized_keys  due to a known issue in Linux provisioning agent."

Comment: it would be the pub key, you can generate it with ssh-keygen for example. its the key on your local machine, not on the vm (it will get added there during provisioning). path to the key on the vm is basically hardcoded

Comment: fixed, with changing admin_username and  ssh_keys path values...

Comment: can you share what you did to fix it. I still   get the error
admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  }

Comment: never mind - figured it out. Another option is to use TF to create the ssh key resource.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, In my case I was creating 3 VMs using terraform.
and I fixed it by changing the **admin_username** in the **azurerm_linux_virtual_machine**

and the **username** in the **admin_ssh_key**

here is my case ()

```
username         = "${var.username}${count.index}"

admin_username   = "${var.username}${count.index}"
```

the use of variables is because I'm using the count to make more than 1 vm.