# Terraform Azure provider - VM encryption at rest

Tags: azure, encryption, terraform-provider-azure

I'm getting an error while trying to set up a VM with a Key vault. This is part of the code I think is relevant.

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "example" {
  name         = "TF-key-example"
  key_vault_id = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.id}"
  key_type     = "RSA"
  key_size     = 2048

  key_opts = [
    "decrypt",
    "encrypt",
    "sign",
    "unwrapKey",
    "verify",
    "wrapKey",
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_disk_encryption_set" "example" {
  name                = "example-set"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.location}"
  key_vault_key_id    = "${azurerm_key_vault_key.example.id}"
  
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "disk-encryption" {
  key_vault_id = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.id}"

  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
  key_permissions = [
    "create",
    "get",
    "list",
    "wrapkey",
    "unwrapkey",
  ]
  secret_permissions = [
    "get",
    "list",
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "disk-encryption-read-keyvault" {
  scope                = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.id}"
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = "${azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.identity.0.principal_id}"
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Error: Error creating Linux Virtual Machine "example-vm" (Resource
> Group "Encrypt-resources"):
> compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request:
> StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="KeyVaultAccessForbidden"
> Message="Unable to access key vault resource
> 'https://tf-keyvault-example.vault.azure.net/keys/TF-key-example/*****'
> to enable encryption at rest. Please grant get, wrap and unwrap key
> permissions to disk encryption set 'example-set'. Please visit
> https://aka.ms/keyvaultaccessssecmk for more information."

Where and how should I add the permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error print - `Please grant get, wrap and unwrap key permissions to disk encryption set 'example-set'.`

Add the following block:

```sh
# grant the Managed Identity of the Disk Encryption Set access to Read Data from Key Vault
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "disk-encryption" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id

  key_permissions = [
    "get",
    "wrapkey",
    "unwrapkey",
  ]

  tenant_id = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.identity.0.tenant_id
  object_id = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.identity.0.principal_id
}


# grant the Managed Identity of the Disk Encryption Set "Reader" access to the Key Vault
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "disk-encryption-read-keyvault" {
  scope                = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id         = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.identity.0.principal_id
}
```

More about [azurerm_key_vault_access_policy](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/key_vault_access_policy.html) and [azurerm_role_assignment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/role_assignment.html).

**Update-**

The issue was related to not specifying the correct `object_id`.
Later on, The Machine that builds the Terraform missed the SSH file path(e.g -`"~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"`) .
Fixed by running this command:

```sh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

After that, the key vault permission was missing access policy to terraform user.

Besides all that, the sequence of the resources was mixed. fixed that to a more logical sequence.

The full and working code can be found [here](https://pastebin.pl/view/aba5a14a).

Comment: Thank you. It is already part of my code (edited the code above) so I don't believe this is the issue.

Comment: Can you share the whole terraform? is will be easier to debug https://shrib.com

Comment: You point `azurerm_key_vault_access_policy` resource to `data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id` which is not the id of the object. fix that according to the code I posted above. it should work :)

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm getting this error:
Error: Error creating Linux Virtual Machine "example-vm" (Resource Group "Encrypt-resources"): compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidParameter" Message="Destination path for SSH public keys is currently limited to its default value /home/adminuser/.ssh/authorized_keys  due to a known issue in Linux provisioning agent." Target="linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.path"
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55143703/9931092

Comment: I tried this before, but I'm getting an error:
Error: Error decoding "admin_ssh_key.0.public_key" for public key data

  on main.tf line 109, in resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example":
 109: resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221106/discussion-between-amit-baranes-and-omer-shliva).

Answer (score 0):

As Amit Baranes pointed out, you need to set the access policy for your encryption set.

In your above example you grant your data source client ID access to the key vault by way of access policy. The identity of your encryption set however only gets read to the vault by way of role.

Tucked away [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/windows_virtual_machine.html) the AzureRM VM resource documentation states:

> NOTE: The Disk Encryption Set must have the Reader Role Assignment
> scoped on the Key Vault - in addition to an Access Policy to the Key
> Vault

You need to make sure you grant the encryption ID both the read role and an access policy.

A possible resulting full block looks like this, where we give your service principal and the identity access to the vault by way of an access policy. We also retain the read role

```
    resource "azurerm_key_vault_key" "example" {
      name         = "TF-key-example"
      key_vault_id = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.id}"
      key_type     = "RSA"
      key_size     = 2048
    
      key_opts = [
        "decrypt",
        "encrypt",
        "sign",
        "unwrapKey",
        "verify",
        "wrapKey",
      ]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_disk_encryption_set" "example" {
      name                = "example-set"
      resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"
      location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.location}"
      key_vault_key_id    = "${azurerm_key_vault_key.example.id}"
      
      identity {
        type = "SystemAssigned"
      }
    }

    resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "service-principal" {
      key_vault_id = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.id}"
    
      tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
      object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
      key_permissions = [
        "create",
        "get",
        "list",
        "wrapkey",
        "unwrapkey",
      ]
      secret_permissions = [
        "get",
        "list",
      ]
    }

    resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "encryption-set" {
      key_vault_id = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.id}"
    
      tenant_id = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.identity.0.tenant_id
      object_id = azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.identity.0.principal_id

      key_permissions = [
        "create",
        "get",
        "list",
        "wrapkey",
        "unwrapkey",
      ]
      secret_permissions = [
        "get",
        "list",
      ]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "disk-encryption-read-keyvault" {
      scope                = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.id}"
      role_definition_name = "Reader"
      principal_id         = "${azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.identity.0.principal_id}"
    }
```

You would probably want to reduce the access for the service principal, however i left it as is for now.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm getting this error:
Error: Error creating Linux Virtual Machine "example-vm" (Resource Group "Encrypt-resources"): compute.VirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidParameter" Message="Destination path for SSH public keys is currently limited to its default value /home/adminuser/.ssh/authorized_keys  due to a known issue in Linux provisioning agent." Target="linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.path"
Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed `Reader` role is not fit anymore, you now need to use `Key Vault Crypto Service Encryption User`.

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "disk-encryption-read-keyvault" {
  scope                = "${azurerm_key_vault.example.id}"
  role_definition_name = "Key Vault Crypto Service Encryption User"
  principal_id         = ${azurerm_disk_encryption_set.example.identity.0.principal_id}"
}
```